# Java - How to Compile a single file with Java Eclipse

Tags: java, compilation, console

I am trying to compile one file in a java project, but I am seeing other result (result of another file ) in console. I even tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> but the same thing happened

In the dropdown of Run button of Java I am not finding the current file name but if I start a new project and run the file it is compiling.
Note:I am a beginner in Java.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the class or to run it?

Comment: I want to run it @iberbeu

Comment: @JBNizet I want to see the result of a .java file ,but in console it is showing someother file result.

Comment: If you want to run it be sure that the class has a `public void main` method and then right click on the file -> Run as -> Java application

Comment: java may have dependencies like in other langs but in java it doesn't required to link them with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class has to define a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Then find the Java file in the project explorer, right-click on it, and choose "run as Java application".

Comment: can I save this file with either names.PassOb.java or Block.java http://pastebin.com/t7Jq9sdm

Comment: The file name has to be the same (+ extension ".java") as the public class (or interface) defined inside the file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the info in the answer already selected, others having this or a similar problem should chech the "Run Configurations" panel to make sure the setting are correct for the app you are launching.  Check

[image: Run Configurations]

[image: Run Configurations]